# How do I present Prism module views?

Tags: silverlight, prism

I'm writing a prism application, I've just created my 1st module, fired it all up and amazingly - it works.

The application is going to grow soon(TM), and I'll be facing the need to host those modules in separate GUI elements.

What type of GUI elements would you recommend to host the modules?
Is it possible to data-bind a module to some control like a tab-control? How is it done?
Is there some kind of a dock manager (similiar to AvalonDock) for Silverlight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at StockTrader sample project provided with PRISM? It has in Shell.xaml AnimatedTabControl (inherited from TabControl) to which are bound modules: WatchModule (look at WatchListController.cs file) and PositionModule (look at PositionModule.cs file).

[Edit]

Take a look also at [Prism Explorer](http://www.ideablade.com/DevforceSilverlight/DevForceSilverlight_PrismExplorer.aspx) sample project, which is using TabControl in Shell.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the AnimatedTabControl. It appears it's not willing to display tabitems' headers properly in SL3. Anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 1):

There IS dock manager, check silverlight toolkit ( it is installed with sl4 or you can take it [here](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/Wikipage) )
Also there is an example of binding controls to tab control tabs with MEF on channel 9